# Google App Engine Eclipse Error: Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /Applications/eclipse

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I updated to the latest app engine version 1.8.4 and the latest Eclipse plugin for app engine. I am using Eclipse version:

Eclipse Standard/SDK

Version: Kepler Release

Build id: 20130614-0229

Google App Engine Java SDK 1.8.4    1.8.4   com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle.feature.feature.group    Google, Inc.

Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2   3.4.0.v201309051717-rel-r42 com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group  Google, Inc.

When I try to launch my project I get this error. If I switch back to 1.8.1 it works fine. I am using Google Cloud Endpoints, but otherwise nothing too exotic, no Spring, etc.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much deleting and searching around I found I had Eclipse in a folder under Applications called "eclipse keplar", which apparently Eclipse didn't like, so I:

1. Uninstalled Google App engine plugin and 1.8.4
2. Moved the app to a folder called "eclipse".
3. Started eclipse, re-installed the plugin and 1.8.4
4. Restart eclipse, delete the debug configuration.
5. It worked!

So I think there might be a bug in the plugin that assumes, on a Mac at least, Eclipse lives in /Applications/eclipse.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Did your Eclipse folder had a space in its name ?

Seems it is the same problem mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530157/error-opening-zip-file-or-jar-manifest-missing-c-program). Long directory name with spaces.

He solved the problem by going to the vm arguments in the run configurations and then putting double quote around parameters that have spaces in them like long directory names. It has solved the problem for me too.