# Google Cloud Endpoint error at Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

While trying to run local dev server

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing /../appengine-agent.jar
```

I am trying solution [Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:\Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530157/error-opening-zip-file-or-jar-manifest-missing-c-program)

But where and how  should I alter the default -javaagent: ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by http://www.itkeyword.com/doc/7711578960168911246/error-opening-zip-file-or-jar-manifest-missing-in-maven-with-gae-and-spring-roo

I tried deleting all the repositories I have downloaded and right clicked on the project and configured it to "clean compile". Then the folder was automatically downloaded.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your appengine-web.xml:

```
<runtime>java8</runtime>
```

Comment: Thank you !! , I spend hours trying to solve this issue !