# How to handle space in argument in MAVEN_OPTS from the command line?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have some issues passing arguments to my `mvn` command through `MAVEN_OPTS` when there's a space, and specifically a javaagent parameters. I have also followed [this recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530157/error-opening-zip-file-or-jar-manifest-missing-c-program) to double quote the part after the semicolon but with no luck.

The command I am using is this:

```sh
$ export MAVEN_OPTS='-javaagent:"/Users/teras/Library/Application Support/CrossMobile/Plugins/cmxray.jar"'
$ echo $MAVEN_OPTS
-javaagent:"/Users/teras/Library/Application Support/CrossMobile/Plugins/cmxray.jar"
$ mvn -P desktop,run install -B -e
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : "/Users/teras/Library/Application
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. I am on OSX, using bash, if this helps.

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried like this: `-javaagent:"/Users/teras/Library/Application\ Support/CrossMobile/...` ?

Comment: @leopal Unfortunately, same problem: `Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : "/Users/teras/Library/Application\`

Comment: I could only fix this by editing the mvn command script and quoting $MAVEN_OPTS in the exec "$JAVACMD" command at the end of the script. No idea what sideeffects it may cause.

`exec "$JAVACMD" \ "$MAVEN_OPTS "`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid, you can't do that easily. If you [look at the `mvn` script](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/a2b800de32cdb9adc1e64a43a0fc32e3ba878103/apache-maven/src/bin/mvn#L191-L199) you can see it does not put `$MAVEN_OPTS` in quotes.

So unless there is a trick I'm not aware of, there is no way to escape the space.

You can fix that locally by editing your `mvn` script. If you used `homebrew` to install Maven you can find it in `/usr/local/Cellar/maven/<VERSION>/libexec/bin/mvn`. Make a copy of the script (so you can restore it if something goes wrong) and then find those lines at the end of the file (may be a bit different depending on the version):

```sh
exec "$JAVACMD" \
  $MAVEN_OPTS \
  $MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS \
  -classpath "${CLASSWORLDS_JAR}" \
  "-Dclassworlds.conf=${MAVEN_HOME}/bin/m2.conf" \
  "-Dmaven.home=${MAVEN_HOME}" "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=${MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR}" \
  ${CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER} "$@"
```

and add quotes around the variables so it looks like this:

```sh
exec "$JAVACMD" \
  "$MAVEN_OPTS" \
  "$MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS" \
  -classpath "${CLASSWORLDS_JAR}" \
  "-Dclassworlds.conf=${MAVEN_HOME}/bin/m2.conf" \
  "-Dmaven.home=${MAVEN_HOME}" "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=${MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR}" \
  ${CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER} "$@"
```

I am not sure if this is a Maven bug or it's this way on purpose. It looks like [the issue was reported already](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4559) but there seems to be some pushback from the maven team.

**UPDATE**

After reading through the comments of the above issue, I found [this one](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4559?focusedCommentId=15633691&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-15633691) which explains why this may not be a good solution after all:

> If you quote `$MAVEN_OPTS` when used here, the java executable will see it  as 1 parameter, not multiple ones, so if you have `MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx256m -Dparam=\"with space\""`, then java will understand a `Xmx` value of `256m -Dparam="with space"`...
>
> If you don't quote it, then every space separated token (even if it was escaped when declaring `MAVEN_OPTS`) will be considered a separate argument, so `-Dparam="with space"` will be understood as trying to launch the `space"` main class with the `-Dparam="with system property`...

Comment: Apparently is does not in borune shell. See the comments in the issue.