Bash - storing string with spaces and quotes in environment variable not being processed correctly with Maven
Maven supports the MAVEN_ARGS environment variable.
I want to add the argument -Dsomeparam="-X -A" and run Maven.
But when I do this, it's clear it's trying to split the argument via spaces and fails:
Unable to parse command line options: Unrecognized option: -A"
Which means the quoting is not correct.
Simple reproducer:
#!/bin/bash

MAVEN_ARGS="-Dsomeparam=\"-X -A\"" mvn --version


Where do you need someparam? In your tests? What is their purpose? Have you tried first to run via plain command line instead of creating a bash script?

I have many Maven commands, that need a common, centralised argument configuration - hence the environment variable. If write it without that, it's mvn --version -Dsomeparam="-X -A" which works fine. So it's an escaping issue for sure.

It looks like this may actually be a Maven issue - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57819378

Why do you need those -D.. parts? What's the purpose of that? For testing? For your production code?
